# Excluding pandas rows based on a String value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas table that contains a column which has a String datatype. What I need is to exclude any rows that have "Not found" as a string inside them from the data frame. I am currently trying:

df[df.some_column != "Not found"] but that is not working

Looking forward to replies.

Sample data:

```
card_number effective_date  expiry_date grouping_name       Ac. Year code
0       1206090    28 Sep 2012  21 Aug 2013    Dummy no.1  201213
1       1206090    21 Feb 2013  21 Aug 2013   Dummy no.2   201213
2       1206090    28 Sep 2012  30 Nov 2012    Dummy no.3  201213
3       1206090    03 Dec 2012  21 Aug 2013    Dummy no.3  201213
4       1206090    23 Apr 2013  31 Aug 2013   Dummy no.4   201213
5       1206090    28 Sep 2012  21 Aug 2013    Dummy no.5  201213
6       1206090    28 Sep 2012  21 Aug 2013    Dummy no.6  201213
7       1206090    24 Oct 2012  07 Aug 2013     Not found  201213
8       1206090    08 Jan 2013  08 Jan 2013     Not found  201213
9       1206090    08 Jan 2013  31 Aug 2013     Not found  201213
10    Not found    03 Jul 2013  21 Aug 2013    Dummy no.1  201213
11    Not found    03 Jul 2013  21 Aug 2013   Dummy no.2   201213
```

Extra note: My string matching must be extremely weird... When running df[grouping_name] != "Not found" I get true for 7,8,9... does anyone know why?

Comment: you need to use `str.contains`; see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains); as in `df.some_column.str.contains('Not Found', na=False, regex=False)`

Comment: TypeError: contains() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'... besides that would find only the columns with the value... I want the column without such values

Comment: add `~` to the beginning and drop `regex=False`; i guess that is added in `13.1`;

Comment: This is weird... when matching and seeing whether some rows will return true for this check... rows 7,8,9 are still false regardless of the string matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df['some_column'] != "Not found"]
```

Solution With sample data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df

    card_number effective_date  expiry_date grouping_name   Ac. Year code
0    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.1  201213
1    1206090     21 Feb 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.2  201213
2    1206090     28 Sep 2012     30 Nov 2012     Dummy no.3  201213
3    1206090     03 Dec 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.3  201213
4    1206090     23 Apr 2013     31 Aug 2013     Dummy no.4  201213
5    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.5  201213
6    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.6  201213
7    1206090     24 Oct 2012     07 Aug 2013     Not found   201213
8    1206090     08 Jan 2013     08 Jan 2013     Not found   201213
9    1206090     08 Jan 2013     31 Aug 2013     Not found   201213
10   Not found   03 Jul 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.1  201213
11   Not found   03 Jul 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.2  201213


df[df['grouping_name'] != 'Not found']

card_number effective_date  expiry_date grouping_name   Ac. Year code
0    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.1  201213
1    1206090     21 Feb 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.2  201213
2    1206090     28 Sep 2012     30 Nov 2012     Dummy no.3  201213
3    1206090     03 Dec 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.3  201213
4    1206090     23 Apr 2013     31 Aug 2013     Dummy no.4  201213
5    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.5  201213
6    1206090     28 Sep 2012     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.6  201213
10   Not found   03 Jul 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.1  201213
11   Not found   03 Jul 2013     21 Aug 2013     Dummy no.2  201213
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: There you go... grouping_name can't have Not found in it.

Comment: I am getting expected output

Comment: My string comparisons are unfortunately thinking that the Not found in the table doesn't equal to regular Not found string for some reason

Comment: Try after casting it to `str` - `df[df['grouping_name'].apply(str) != 'Not found']`

Comment: Still no luck... this is extremely weird

Comment: Yep, that is weird. Are you getting any error? You might have to show what you are doing from beginging.

Comment: Seems like there is some memory issue going on there... I exported df and imported it back in and your solution worked. This means that there is some weird pointer issue going on there.